# how to validate textbox input as a digit in netbeans

Tags: java, validation, netbeans-7

my problem is how to **validate**  textbox input as a **digit** and the **textbox** shouldn't  be empty.
i need to check these 2 at once code segment

//i code for not emty

if(jTextField1.getText())

Comment: u can check it by Getting key code. have u tried?

Comment: just try to check the pattern for the Digits 
String regex = "^[0-9]";
String data = "23343453521";
System.out.println(data.matches(regex));

Answer (score 0):

try this and that was having some thing wrong pattern.

```
try {
            String regex = "[0-9]+";
            String data = jTextField1.getText();
            System.out.println(data.matches(regex));


            if (!data.matches(regex)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please Enter Digites");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I often use try/NumberFormatException, to make sure the result is valid:
(I suppose you fill an object's field with the value the user entered into the textbox)

For example:

`try {mobjSomeObject.setSomeProp(Integer.parseInt(txtTextBox.getText()));} 
  catch (NumberFormatException nFE) {... do something if not a number ...;}`

Comment: and how that property u will set? i think that is not good way to do it

Comment: This is a property set:`mobjSomeObject.setSomeProp(...)` 
The try/catch only assures the property'll have a number as a value. At the catch part you can set to 0 or send a message to the user or whatever...
Why is it not good?

Comment: but u will give validation if u get exception isnt it?

Comment: I think it's a matter of your choice.
As an exception is raised, nothing is given to the property. 
Then in the catch section you can assign a default value OR even initiate a 'cancelEdit' to the object - if needed. 

In fact I often use a JDialog to notify the user AND assign a default value. It's enough in the most of the cases.

Comment: well yes that is correct but dont u think checking the pattern would be more better.:)